# XML BerkeleyDB with C#

Tags: c#, xml, database-connection, berkeley-db-xml

I would like to use C# as a wrapper application for Oracle Berkeley XML database.
I tried to find how to do this on the Internet but could not.

Basically, I am a new user for this kind of native XML database and I know that lots of users are using Java with BerkeleyDB. But I need to work with C# and I need a first step.

1- Do I need to install specific software in Visual Studio 2010 to run Berkeley XML DB?
2- How can I connect to the Berkeley database using C# and store XML and XSD?
3- How can I run any basic path query?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a C++ and a Java API on top of Berkeley DB XML. If you want to use C#, you may want to look at this project. It's a few years old, but the basic concepts and approach are still valid.

Good luck.